# How to use item self as parameter in databind inner method

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

```
        <ListView
            x:Name="List"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind itemlist}"
            SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                    <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="str"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                            Text="{x:Bind /* the method i want to use here */ }" />
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

To use method in DataTemplate,it seems that the method requires at least a parameter that was the property of databind item .
However, is there any way to use the method that use the item self rather than its property to work?(not ValueConverter)

Comment: You can only bind to properties not methods

Comment: What do you want to display in the `TextBlock`? What method are you referring to? How is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

`Text="{Binding}"` or `Text="{Binding.}"`